# Sort array by alphabetical value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an index array that has two elements per index and I'm wanting to sort the array by the `name`, alphabetically and descending. Are one of the PHP functions such as `sort`, `asort` or `usort` good for this job? I've tried to no avail, undoubtedly because I'm incorrectly using the functions.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Array currently looks like:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2611)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Agile QA"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2892)
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "User Stories"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3722)
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "2nd test category"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(102)
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "A/B Testing"
  }
}
```

Comment: usort works for this fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function has the perfect example for this. I've changed it for your case, so `$array` is the array you just showed:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}


usort($array, "cmp");

?>
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I tried this exact same thing before, but was incorrectly referencing the wrong thing in the return and was confused as to what the parameters `$a` and `$b` were. Thank you very much Loko.

Non-related P.S. I love getting downvoted for misunderstanding a PHP function even after extensive research. Worse than Reddit you lot ;)

Comment: Yeah I dont know why it was downvoted. The question itself seems fine to me.